# Can I transfer .epub to the kindle via usb?

Tags: kindle, epub

I'm just in love with the new Kindle 3. Is it currently possible to transfer my epub files to the device via usb? I know, it's not allways been working...

Answer (score 21):

I do not believe the Kindle can natively display .epub files. One option is to use the excellent free [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) software to convert the .epub to a .mobi file, Kindle displays that format very well (Amazon's own format is a modified .mobi). Then you can copy the .mobi file via USB to your Kindle, or alternately use Calibre's built-in email-to-Kindle function to transfer the file via Whispernet.

Comment: +1 for Calibre. The ePub to mobi converter works great.

Comment: Calibre worked great for me!

Comment: does this still work in 2016, for newer Amazon devices?

Comment: Still works fine for loading files into my Kindle app on my phone.

Comment: Due to some firmware upgrade of the Kindle, it no longer supports mobi files. It appears that the files need to be sent to amazon. Calibre was discontinued.

Comment: Calibre is certainly not discontinued. They just recently put out the 7.0 release (Nov 2023). If `.mobi` isn't supported on Kindle any more you can use Calibre to convert to Kindle's native `.azw3` format.

Answer (score 3):

Check [EPUB to Kindle converter](http://epubkindle.com) (but only for Windows OS). It's small, simple and run fast in comparision with Calibre.

> EPUB is the best modern format for electronic publication and Kindle
>   (read our article about Amazon Kindle devices) is one of the best
>   e-book reader. Our converter helps you to cooperate these two
>   beautiful things.
>
> EPUB to Kindle converter allows you to: — Look through the book covers
>   in EPUB format available on your computer. — Check properties of these
>   EPUB books (author, title etc). — Convert one or several EPUB files to
>   MOBI files into folder on your computer — Convert your EPUB files and
>   upload them to Kindle device.

[image]

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

If the USB doesn't work- like mine didn't - go to Amazon.com and "manage my kindle" The book should appear and you can download and sync with all your various kindles.

Comment: If it's a book you bought from Amazon.  You can buy e-books elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon supports the ePub format in late 2022. You can use the send to kindle service. No need to convert the epub format.

[How To Transfer/Send EPUB To Kindle EReaders [New Strategy]](https://www.isummersoft.com/transfer-epub-to-kindle-in-late-2022/)

And it's also reported that the send to kindle app will support ePub soon.

Comment: It is best to include the relevant details from the link, in case of future [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can transfer the ePub to Kindle via USB.

But finally you will find that the ePub is not shown on your Kindle as Kindle doesn't support ePub format reading.

The best solution is to convert the ePub to Kindle Mobi.

Comment: While accurate this isn't very useful.

Comment: Why is this not useful?